# typescript compilation errors never stop compilation

Tags: typescript

Below is the content of the index.ts file that I am transpiling to js with default settings of tsconfig --init (tsc v3.2.4)

```
console.log("foo");
these crazy typos will compile all though compilation raises errors
console.log("bar")
```

The typescript compiler will output a build whatever the input may be.

Is there a way to control this ?

For example: make typescript compiler output nothing if errors are raised during compilation.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the `noEmitOnError` flag in https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html