# How to stop Next.js compilation if there are Typescript errors?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have Next.js 13.1.1 and Typescript 4.9.4 project setup. Here is a simple Button component that has required props:

```js
interface BannerProps {
  isSidebarOpen: boolean
}

export const Banner = (props: BannerProps) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <button>
        {props.isSidebarOpen ? <CloseIcon /> : <HamburgerIcon />}
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

If I miss passing `isSidebarOpen` to the `<Banner />`, my IDE highlights the error:

```
Property 'isSidebarOpen' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'BannerProps'.
```

Nevertheless, Next.js app compiles. This means I can forget passing props in many places after recently adding required props and waste time figuring out reasons for unexpected behavior.

I couldn't find working configs for allowing Next.js to fail compilation if Typescript errors are present. Is this a reasonable expectation? `noEmitOnError` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56829016/16407971) doesn't change this behavior. Also tried [this config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67133034/16407971) without success.

The closest I got was using `tsc --noEmit`, but don't want to run scripts manually and chase these errors once they pile up.

Comment: It compiles only for development. Have you tried `next build`?

Comment: It fails as expected when building. But I would like that behavior during development as well.

Comment: you could use tsc-watch, which you can configure to build your app on each success - although this is a bit slower

Comment: I don't think it is a huge issue though as your IDE is prompting you that it is incorrect already